What is the syntax for a for loop over an index with increment?
What is the syntax for having a for loop in zig with an increment?
In the code snippet below I wrote how it would look like in F#.
But how does it look like in zig?
In C it would be something like for (x = 3*x0; x <= x1; x += 2*x0).
fn foo(x0: i32, x1: i32) {
  for (3*x0..2*x0..x1) |x| {
     // ...
  }
}


I'm not a zig expert, but perusing documentation online, it doesn't appear that the zig for loop construct allows for arbitrary iteration. It's less like a C for loop and more like a C# foreach loop.
You'd want to use a while loop with a continue expression (after the :) in this situation.
var x : i32 = 3 * x0;

while (x <= x1) : (x += 2 * x0) {
    // body of the loop
}


Yes - it looks like that - but I hoped they just forgot to write some nice documentation and samples.

The while loop has the advantage that you can specify the type of the loop variable (example). The capture of a for loop is always a usize (docs).

Full code example:
const std = @import("std");
   
fn foo(x0: i32, x1: i32) void {
    var x = 3 * x0;
    while (x <= x1) : (x += 2 * x0) {
        std.debug.print("x: {}\n", .{x});
    }
}
    
pub fn main() void {
    const x0: i32 = 2;
    const x1: i32 = 20;
    foo(x0, x1);
}

